# C++ Matrix Class with Operator Overloading

Tags: c++, operators

I was implementing a small dense matrix class and instead of plan get/set operators I wanted to use operator overloading to make the API more usable and coherent.

What I want to achieve is pretty simple:

```
template<typename T>
class Matrix
{
public:

    /* ... Leaving out CTOR and Memory Management for Simplicity */

    T operator() (unsigned x, unsigned y){/* ... */ }
};


Matrix<int> m(10,10);
int value = m(5,3); // get the value at index 5,3
m(5,3) = 99; // set the value at index 5,3
```

While getting the value is straight forward by overloading `operator()`, I can't get my head around defining the setter. From what I understood the operator precedence would call `operator()` before the assignment, however it is not possible to overload `operator()` to return a correct lvalue.

What is the best approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You can't define two `operator()` methods that have the same signature but return different values in one class

Comment: I suggest using `operator[]` instead of `operator()` which is more coherent with the C++ language itself considering the syntax for multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @Antonio: That is a bad recommendation. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.10

Comment: @grundprinzip: have one T& operator() and one const T& operator() const will suffice, the "get" operation will then just simply copy from the reference instead from the returned object

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I dispute that "it's not possible" to do the correct thing:

```
struct Matrix
{
  int & operator()(size_t i, size_t j) { return data[i * Cols + j]; }
  const int & operator()(size_t i, size_t j) const { return data[i * Cols + j]; }

  /* ... */

private:
  const size_t Rows, Cols;
  int data[Rows * Cols];  // not real code!
};
```

Now you can say, `m(2,3) = m(3,2) = -1;` etc.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this works because you return a reference to the value that will be changed. Do you see any problems with more complex types, e.g. if the matrix is templated?

Comment: The overload works because the signatures are different, one is const and one is not const. Assignment works because you return a reference. You should most definitely template this on the value type, and possibly also on the sizes.

Comment: I would change the `const int &` return type to plain `int`. There is no point (in most cases) in returning a constant reference to `int`

Comment: @David: Sure, for `int` you're right, but if you are going to template this, the const-reference is maybe the more general solution. I guess an `is_primitve` typetrait would be the best of both worlds!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is what Kerrek already stated: you can provide an overload by changing the signature of the operator, which in this case can be achieved by modifying the const-ness of the function.

But I would recommend that you at least consider providing a separate setter for the values. The reason is that once you return references to your internal data structures you loose control of what external code does with your data. It might be ok in this case, but consider that if you decided to add range validation to the implementation (i.e. verify that no value in the matrix is above X or below Y), or wished to optimize some calculation on the matrix (say the sum of all of the elements in the matrix is an often checked value, and you want to optimize away the calculation by pre-caching the value and updating it on each field change) it is much easier to control with a method that receives the value to set.

Comment: Basically, this is what I initially wanted. I searched for a way to use the `operator()` notation without actually exposing my internal data type, but somehow re-route the call to an assignment.